# default value for textarea doesn't work

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I have the following in my razor view:

```
@model Product

 <form ...>
     ...
     <div class="form-group">
       <label asp-for="Description"></label>
          <textarea asp-for="Description" class="form-control" cols="20" rows="3">Why is this default value disappearing?</textarea>
     </div>
     ...
  </form>
```

For some unknown magic, the default textarea value disappear.

Comment: Does your `Description` field in `Product` has blank value? Try to load textarea without Description like this `<textarea class="form-control" cols="20" rows="3">Why is this default value disappearing?</textarea>` This will show you default value.

Answer (score 1):

Textarea with asp-for attribute handle by TextAreaTagHelper and generated textarea with tagHelper not used from value that you set, for this you can use following syntax in ViewModel:

```
public class Product
{
    ...
    public string Description{get; set;} => "Why is this default value disappearing?";
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bound elements can be defaulted using constructor of the model:

```
public class Product()
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    //other properties

    public Product() //the constructor
    {
      Description = "Put the default value here!";
      //other default values
     }
}
```